# Consulta en dos modelos en django

Tags: html, python, django

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta, la idea es de una tienda online simple, si la marca de algún producto coincide con la busqueda, que aparezca en la lista con sus respectivos atributos.

```
def buscar(request):
        if  "busca" in request.GET and request.GET['busca']:
            resultado = []
            consulta = request.GET.get("busca")
            cervezas =  Nacionales.objects.filter(marca__icontains=consulta)
            resultado.append(cervezas)
            icervezas = Importadas.objects.filter(imarca__icontains=consulta)
            resultado.append(icervezas)

            for valor in resultado:

                return render(request, 'resultados.html', {'resultado': resultado})
         else:
            return render(request, 'resultados.html')
```

Creo que el def buscar sí funciona, pero he probado varias cosas y no logro sacar los resultados correctamente por la url.

estos son los modelos:

```
class Nacionales(models.Model):
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    variedad = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='foto_productos', blank=True)
    precio = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Importadas(models.Model):
    imarca = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ivariedad = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    iorigen = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ifoto = models.ImageField(upload_to='foto_productos', blank=True)
    iprecio = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

y el template:

```
{% if resultado %}
    <ul>
        {% for a in resultado %}
        <li>
                <p>Marca: {{a.marca}}</p>
                <p>Variedad: {{a.variedad}}</p>
                <p>Precio: {{a.precio}}</p>     
        </li>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for b in resultado %}
        <li>
                <p>Marca: {{b.imarca}}</p>
                <p>Variedad: {{b.ivariedad}}</p>
                <p>Precio: {{b.iprecio}}</p>
                <img class="ifoto" src="{{b.ifoto.url}}" alt="img">

        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
        <p>No se encontraron resultados</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quiza si eliminas el for de la funcion, ya que no entiendo para que lo tienes si en realidad no lo utilizas.

```
def buscar(request):
         if  "busca" in request.GET and request.GET['busca']:
            resultado = []
            consulta = request.GET.get("busca")
            cervezas =  Nacionales.objects.filter(marca__icontains=consulta)
            resultado.append(cervezas)
            icervezas = Importadas.objects.filter(imarca__icontains=consulta)
            resultado.append(icervezas)
            return render(request, 'resultados.html', {'resultado': resultado})
         else:
            return render(request, 'resultados.html')
```

Comment: @AgustinPisuClavell según veo tu vista y tu template en ningún momento pasas como variables de contexto `a` o `b`, al template y veo que estas iterando dichas "variables" de contexto (que no existen según tu vista) en tu template. La variable de contexto que pasas al template es `resultados`, dicha variable de contexto es la que deberías iterar no?